# Generate unique non repeating pairs in a list in O(n)

Tags: list, python-3.x, combinations

How do we generate unique non repeating pairs such that (x,y) = (y,x) are not repeated.

Say we have a list `[3,6,9]`. Then, answer is `(3, 6) (3, 9) (6, 9)`
If the list is `[3,6]`. Then answer is `(3,6)`

This can be done using 2 for loops, but we want to be preferably done in `O(n)` (using max one loop)

Is there a pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: This task can not be accomplished in `O(n)`, where `n` is the input size a.k.a. your list length.

Answer (score 1):

The Pythonic way to do it is to use the standard library generator (https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

for comb in combinations([3,6,9], 2):
    print(comb)
```

As the docs say, the number of combinations is `n! / (2 * (n-2)!)`, which I guess is `O(n^2)`. So it can't be done in O(n) time.

Comment: So there isnt an O(n) solution to this problem?

Comment: If `n` is the length of the original list, then no. Even if you magically knew the answer and only had to put it in a list, that takes O(n^2) time.